# How to choose the word in the dictionary menu?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a English dictionary using python 2. I created a dictionary. for example, "home" and "horse" in the dictionary's key. If the user types "ho", "home" and "horse" will come. I put these in the bottom line. But when the user selects word 1, I want to call the key and value in the dictionary that I set first. How can I do it?

```
myEngDict = {"horse": "The horse (Equus ferus caballus) is one of two extant subspecies of Equus ferus","home": "the place where one lives permanently, especially as a member of a family or household."}

def Words():
    word_List = []
    count = 0
    search_words = raw_input("Please enter a search term: ")
    for i in myEngDict.keys():
        if i.startswith(search_words):
            count+=1
            word_List.append(i)
            print "{}{}{}".format(count,".", i)
        else:
            pass
    choose = input("Which one?")
```

For example, if "home" comes out first, user choose 1:

Program display:

```
home: the place where one lives permanently, especially as a member of a family or household.
```

Comment: The indentation of your code is incorrect...and I can't determine what is ought to be. Please [edit] your question and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `raw_input` in that final line. Then you need to look up the provided in the `word_List`.

```
while True:
   try:
       choose = int(raw_input("Which one?"))

       # Keep the key as a separate variable for faster reference
       key = word_List[choose - 1]

       # Use labels with the format function. It's easier to read and understand
       print '{label}: {text}'.format(label=key, text=myEngDict[key])

       # Be sure to have a break or return on success.
       return
   except ValueError: 
       # If someone provides 'cat', it will raise an error.
       # Inform the user and go back to the start.
       print 'Please provide an integer'
   except IndexError:
       # The user has provided a value above the length of word_List or 
       # less than one. Again, inform the user and go back to start.
       print 'You must enter a number between 1 and {c}'.format(c=len(word_List))
```

Answer (score 0):

By not changing to much your code, you can just add a print statement after `choose` in your function at the same identation:

```
print ("%s : %s"%(word_List[choose-1], myEngDict[word_List[choose-1]]))
```